# Redirect in Route Service Provider

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I'm currently using the route/model binding to check if there is a valid id for a `Tag` in my database. It's pretty sweet so far but I would like to make sure that:

1. If there is no slug set it should redirect to the slugged url
2. Make sure the slug is correct (in case of update) and redirect to proper slugged url.

---

```
$router->bind('tag_id', function ($id) {

    $tag = \App\Tag::getById($id);

    // if ($tag->slug !== \Request::segment(3))
    // {
    //     return redirect('/tags/' . $tag->id . '/' . $tag->slug);
    // }

    if ($tag instanceof \App\Tag)
    {
        return $tag;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
 });
```

That's my code so far, but no idea how to redirect out of the `RouteServiceProvider` or if it's even possible form there. Is there anyway to do this. I know it would be quite easy for the `/tags/:id` style url, but I would like to catch the incorrect slugs as well if possible.

Comment: Try `redirect(...)->send()`

Comment: ->send() works, thx @lukasgeiter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't particularly like this way but you can trigger the redirect without having it to return from a controller action or route closure by calling `send()` on it. (That works for all kind responses by the way)

```
if ($tag->slug !== \Request::segment(3))
{
    redirect('/tags/' . $tag->id . '/' . $tag->slug)->send();
}
```